# Which one is grammatically correct? And why?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses

##### Which one is grammatically correct? And why?

Those who feel interest to tell lies never prosper in life.

or
Those who feel interested to tell lies never prosper in life.

Comment: Neither _feel interest to `V`_ nor _feel interested to `V`_ is colloquial English.  Normally one _is interested in `V`-ing_ or _feels an interest in `V`-ing_ (though _has an interest_ is more common than _feels_).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Guess both of them are incorrect.